# How I mount an image on linux in fake read-only mode?

Tags: linux, mount, read-only

I have a image, that I want to mount read-only.

I know how to do it: `losetup -r /dev/loop0 /path/to/image`

But the problem is that any attempt to write to this device, will produce an error that the device is read-only.
What I want to have, is the behaviour that is done by many forensic write-blockers, where the device will "lie" About that the drive is writeable, and falsely ACK any write command (tell the Writing process that it was a success), even if the write command never reach the drive or image file.

How can this be accomplished?

Eg, currently, the result is:

```
root@server-desktop:~# losetup /dev/loop1 imagefile
root@server-desktop:~# echo haha > /dev/loop1
root@server-desktop:~# losetup -d /dev/loop1
root@server-desktop:~# cat imagefile
haha
root@server-desktop:~# losetup -r /dev/loop1 imagefile
root@server-desktop:~# echo whatnow > /dev/loop1
-bash: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
root@server-desktop:~# losetup -d /dev/loop1
root@server-desktop:~# cat imagefile
haha
root@server-desktop:~#
```

Result wanted:

```
root@server-desktop:~# losetup /dev/loop1 imagefile
root@server-desktop:~# echo haha > /dev/loop1
root@server-desktop:~# losetup -d /dev/loop1
root@server-desktop:~# cat imagefile
haha
root@server-desktop:~# losetup -r /dev/loop1 imagefile
root@server-desktop:~# echo whatnow > /dev/loop1
root@server-desktop:~# losetup -d /dev/loop1
root@server-desktop:~# cat imagefile
haha
root@server-desktop:~#
```

Notice how the second "echo whatnow" command should return a success even if its readonly. How can this be accomplished? NOTE: This is NOT about supressing any error messages! It should really return a "success" to the Writing process, as I will use this loop device along with ietd (iSCSI Enterprise target).

Note that the command (losetup -r) does not neccessary need to be losetup -r, it can be Another command or process. The main intent is that it should produce a read-only block-device out of a image file, that will accept and ignore any writes. (instead of rejecting writes)

Comment: Not a solution, but maybe a partial workarround depending on your use case.  Would using some kind of "union file system" help where you mount the underlying device RO then something else (file ?) ro for changes - which then can be destroyed afterwards leaving the original disk ?

Comment: This is the solution I have today, by using dmsetup along with a snapshot of about 1mb that is cleaned each reboot of the iSCSI initiator (eg a bootscript on the initiator tells the server to start the cleaning process on the target machine). But sometimes the cleaning process hangs indefinitely, causing the initiator to be stuck in a bootloop. I would rather get rid of the cleaning process completely, and instead discard any Changes immediately.

Comment: What I was proposing was analogous but uses different tools - and I suspect may get round your issues with dmsetup.   If you use aufs you can mount a source ro, and another source rw - this works at the filesystem level rather then the block level - so you don't need to worry about snapshotting or dmcrypt - you just mount your image loopback,ro and merge that with another directory path  - I see no reason the read-write path couldn't be /tmp which automatically gets cleaned on restart.

Comment: It must be on block level since the system which reside on the image is a windows system. Thus the image also needs to contain a bootloader since a PXE client fire up on diskless Machines and boot Windows 7 via iSCSI. Thus, forget file level systems. It must be either a raw image file (have tried with xmount with no success currently) or a (virtual or real) block device. Also, the server does restart very rarely, so /tmp does not get cleaned.

Comment: nbd has a copy on write mode that allows writes that are only visible in one "session" (multiple allowed) and discards them afterwards.